# Why this is happening on NodeJs

Tags: node.js

I am learning node js and when ever i run the code the code will run perfectly but when i change the url location then it will show the error

```
const http = require("http");

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.url === "/") {
    res.end(`<h1>This is Home Page</h1>`);
  }
  if (req.url === "/about") {
    res.end(`<h1>This is about Page</h1>`);
  }
  res.end(`
  <h1>Page not FOund</h1>
  <p> Would you like to go home page </p>
  <a href="/">Home Page</a>
  `);
});

server.listen(5000);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReBcK.png)

Comment: If execution enters either `if`, you're calling `res.end` twice. Add a `return` inside each `if`

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) out for your next questions. It is better for you if you can summarize your problem in the answer title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you are accessing url `/` your `res` will call

```
res.end(`<h1>This is Home Page</h1>`);
```

and then

```
res.end(`
  <h1>Page not FOund</h1>
  <p> Would you like to go home page </p>
  <a href="/">Home Page</a>
`);
```

According to the docs https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_end_chunk_encoding_callback

Calling `end` with a string means passing the string to the `Writable` and then signals that no more data will be written into it. Writing anything after it will raise an error. So basically you need to make sure no more`end('someString')` being called after another.

Fix using `else if` and `else`:

```
if (req.url === "/") {
  res.end(`<h1>This is Home Page</h1>`);
} else if (req.url === "/about") {
  res.end(`<h1>This is about Page</h1>`);
} else {
  res.end(`
  <h1>Page not FOund</h1>
  <p> Would you like to go home page </p>
  <a href="/">Home Page</a>
  `);
}
```

Or maybe use a switch

```
switch (res.url) {
  case '/':
    res.end(`<h1>This is Home Page</h1>`);
    break;
  case '/about':
    res.end(`<h1>This is about Page</h1>`);
    break;
  default:
    res.end(`
      <h1>Page not FOund</h1>
      <p> Would you like to go home page </p>
      <a href="/">Home Page</a>
    `);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const http = require("http");

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.url === "/") {
    return res.end(`<h1>This is Home Page</h1>`);
  }
  if (req.url === "/about") {
    return res.end(`<h1>This is about Page</h1>`);
  }
  return res.end(`
  <h1>Page not FOund</h1>
  <p> Would you like to go home page </p>
  <a href="/">Home Page</a>
  `);
});

server.listen(5000);
```

In nodejs server, before you using res for end of route, u should have a return statement to end of routing, it's sometime have bug with duplicate return data